# Trailhead: Subscribe to Platform Events

Tags: trailhead

Running into a problem for this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_dev_intermediate/modules/platform_events_basics/units/platform_events_subscribe)

I have the following OrderEventTrigger.apxt   apex trigger

```
trigger OrderEventTrigger on Order_Event__e (after insert) { 
    // List to hold all tasks to be created.
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    // Get user Id for task owner
    User usr = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Name='Admin User' LIMIT 1];


    // Iterate through each notification.
    for (Order_Event__e event : Trigger.New) {
        if (event.Has_Shipped__c == true) {
            // Create task 
            Task tk = new Task(Priority='Medium', status='New',subject='Follow up on shipped order ' + event.Order_Number__c, ownerId=usr.Id);
            tasks.add(tk);

        }
   }

    // Insert all tasks corresponding to events received.
    insert tasks;
}
```

running into the following error:

> Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
>   Publishing an Order_Event__e did not create the associated task successfully. Please check your trigger and event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OwnerId` is supposed to be set using the current user Id.

You can use the System method: `UserInfo.getUserId()` to get the current user Id.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I spend so much time on this challenge haha.

Comment: No problem ! Glad I could help.

Comment: make sure you accept the answer if it helped @Josh Adams

Answer (score 0):

This error can also happen when you save the trigger as Inactive - the trigger may have been coded correctly, except that it would not have fired, since it wasn't active.